# How Can I Write a Batch File Where I Start one Program and When that Program Finishes or Closes, Start Another

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, windows-7

For example:

```
@echo off
start C:\Windows\system32\dfrgui.exe /C
```

Wait for defragmentation to finish.

```
start C:\"Program Files (x86)"\CCleaner\CCleaner.exe /AUTO
```

Wait for CCleaner to finish.

```
start C:\Windows\system32\cleanmgr.exe /sagerun:1
```

and so on..
You get the point.
How I can do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start can take a command line argument /WAIT e.g.

```
@echo off
title Test cmd start

start /WAIT wait.cmd 5
start /WAIT cmd /k echo launched second command

pause
```

This simple example uses another script I have written (wait.cmd shown below) as the first command executed, as you will see if you test this with the /WAIT option specified the script allows the first command to finish before continuing:

```
@echo off
rem call with # of seconds to wait

set /a secs=%1
set /a ms=%secs%*1000
echo Process will wait for %secs% seconds and then continue...
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w %ms% > nul
echo.
exit
```

As a side note if you open a cmd session you can find out about the arguments that a command such as start accepts e.g.

[image]

---

**Update following comment**

So to adapt the commands you listed in your question to finish before starting the next command in the script you could use:

```
@echo off
start /WAIT C:\Windows\system32\dfrgui.exe /C
start /WAIT C:\"Program Files (x86)"\CCleaner\CCleaner.exe /AUTO
start /WAIT C:\Windows\system32\cleanmgr.exe /sagerun:1
```

Comment: So there's 5 seconds between each command, isn't there a way to continue just at the time when program finished?

Comment: The wait.cmd program is just an example use (with 5 seconds it is long enough to clearly see that the first program finishes before the second starts). You can use the /WAIT argument with your commands instead of wait.cmd e.g. `start /WAIT C:\Windows\system32\dfrgui.exe /C` will run the defrag until it's finished then proceed with the script.

Comment: I have also added to my answer to clarify.

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I wanted, just an off topic question, why does Disk Defragmenter wont start defragmenting disk C, Is my argument wrong?

Comment: @Giancarlo No problem, just looked up the defrag syntax, you can use the defrag command (from any directory) e.g. use `defrag /?` to see options. There are also more details available here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff458356.aspx

Comment: The program that you were calling `dfrgui` is a graphical user interface (GUI) for defrag, under the hood i wouldn't be at all surprised if it just calls defrag.exe with the options that you have specified via the user interface.